# Uploading gallery images using filesystem in Entity Framework

Tags: image, entity-framework, filesystems, gallery

I want to upload gallery images to ASP.NET MVC 5 application using filesystem upload. I added

```
public IEnumerable<string> GalleryImages { get; set; }
```

to my `ProductModel`, built solution and performed `update-database` in the package manager console. But, the property is not added to the `Product` table and when I try to add and then edit a product, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source'

Also, I added this piece of code to `Edit.cshtl`:

```
@if (!Model.GalleryImages.Any())
{
    <h4>There are no gallery images for this product.</h4>
}

<form action="/AdminPanel/Product/SaveGalleryImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>

<br /><br />

@foreach (var image in Model.GalleryImages)
{
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <img src="/Images/Uploads/Products/@Model.Id/Gallery/Thumbs/@image" />
        @Html.ActionLink("delete", "DeleteImage", "Product", new { @class = "deleteimage", data_name = image })
    </div>
}
<link href="~/Scripts/dropzone/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        //preview image
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("img#imgpreview").attr("src", e.target.result).width(200).height(200);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#ImageUpload").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });

        //dropzone js

        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });

                this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    formData.append("id", @Model.Id);
                });
            }
        };

        //dropzone js
        $("a.deleteimage").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!confirm("confirm deletion"))
                return false;

            var $this = $(this);
            var url = "/admin/shop/DeleteImage";
            var imageName = $this.data("name");

            $.post(url, { id: @Model.Id, imageName: imageName }, function (data) {
                $this.parent().fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Migrations have already been enabled in project

Comment: I got the message when I performed update-database as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

What exactly do you expect as a column datatype when you model it as `List<string>`? SQL Server doesn't have any column data type to handle an arbitrary list of strings....

If you have an 1:n relationship between `ProductModel` and gallery images, you should really have a **separate** model class that holds the image information - e.g. `MyImages`. Then you could add a collection-style property

```
public virtual ICollection<MyImages> GalleryImages
```

to your `ProductModel` class.

SQL Server can't really handle `List<string>` as a column type .....

---

The steps needed to get this done are:

1. Change your C# model class (you've done this already)
2. Run `add-migration migration-name` so that an EF migration is added to your project (you seem to have skipped this step)
3. Run `update-database` to actually apply that migration to the database.

Only if you've completed **ALL 3 steps** in exactly this order are changes from your C# model class actually applied to the database - you **CANNOT** simply skip step #2 ....

Comment: Thanks Marc. I did all 3 steps but again no row is added to Product table. If I change public IEnumerable<string> GalleryImages to public string GalleryImages and update database, the row is added which of course is not the answer.